# Async await its showing undefined

Tags: async-await, ecmascript-2017

```
export default class Search {
constructor(query){
    this.query = query;
}

async getResults() {
    const API_KEY = "1d4e862be156056d16d3390378173c21";

    await fetch(`https://www.food2fork.com/api/search?key=${API_KEY}&q=${this.query}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        const result = data.recipes;
        console.log(result);
    })
    .catch(error => alert('Receive Data Failed'))

};
```

}

import to here..

```
const state = {};

const controlSearch =  async () =>{

    const query = 'pizza'

    if(query){

        state.search = new Search(query);

        await state.search.getResults();

        console.log(state.search.result);

    }
}
```

it store the data from getResults method into a variable. i wondering that it returning a undefined when i called it from state.search.result

Comment: ```const result = data.recipes;``` that you're not doing anything with it. You forgot to set this.result to result. Try ```this.result = data.recipes;``` in your then callback of your search function. It's about variable scope the const you created only exists within your the function.

Answer (score 1):

You never assign anything to `state.search.result`

Replace:

```
const result = data.recipes;
```

with:

```
this.result = data.recipes;
```

That will do the trick. However, it is better design to return values as promise resolution values:

```
getResults() { // drop the async; just return the promise
    const API_KEY = "1d4e862be156056d16d3390378173c21";

    return fetch(`https://www.food2fork.com/api/search?key=${API_KEY}&q=${this.query}`)
//  ^^^^^^
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => this.result = data.recipes);
//                ^^^^^^^^^^^ (return it)
    .catch(error => alert('Receive Data Failed'))
};
```

And in your main code:

```
    state.search = new Search(query);
    console.log(await state.search.getResults());
```